# Cannot push arrays to array - fast-csv, nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, fast-csv

I'm using `fast-csv` npm package to parse incoming csv file and catching event `data` and displaying `row` is absolutely OK. I got what I want here.

> What I've done:

```js
fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
  .pipe(csv.parse({ ignoreEmpty: true, trim: true }))
  .on("error", (error) => console.error(error))
  .on("data", (row) => console.log(row))
  .on("end", (rowCount) => console.log(rowCount));
```

> What I got in `data` event:

```
['Data Entry Form']
['no','name','email','phone','address']
['1','John','john@gmail.com','09111111111','abc']
['2','Mary','mary@gmail.com','09111111111','abc']
```

> What I need:

```js
let data = [];

  fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
    .pipe(csv.parse({ ignoreEmpty: true, trim: true }))
    .on("error", (error) => console.error(error))
    .on("data", (row) => data.push(_.compact(row)))
    .on("end", (rowCount) => console.log(rowCount));

  return res.status(201).send({
    status: "success",
    data,
  });
```

> NOT OK:

`data` is empty and I got no error.

Any Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should respond only when the read stream is ended, like this:

```js
let data = [];

fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
    .pipe(csv.parse({ ignoreEmpty: true, trim: true }))
    .on("error", (error) => console.error(error))
    .on("data", (row) => data.push(_.compact(row)))
    .on("end", (rowCount) => {
        console.log(rowCount);
        res.status(201).send({
            status: "success",
            data,
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can't I access from after read stream is ended because I have so much extra work to do with the data. The csv file will contain 2 types of data which will be inserted into 2 different tables like `students` and `parents` and some information like `state` will need to replace with real `state_id` instead of text because it is a foreign key in student table.

Comment: You missed the point. You're reading from a read stream here, which is asynchronous. After all the data is read, `fs` will emit an `end` event and you can start doing things with your data. If you put that code outside the function registered for the `end` event, it will be executed before the read stream is ended, hence empty data is what you get.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much.